# In AKKA does calling shutdown on a supervisor stop all the actors it's supervising?

Tags: java, scala, akka, actor, akka-supervision

Let's say I have a supervisor that has linked 2 actors. When my app shutsdown I want to shutdown those actors gracefully. Does calling supervisor.shutdown() stop all the actors or do I still need to stop my actors manually?

gracias

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Stopping a supervisor](https://github.com/jboner/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/Supervisor.scala#L163) (calling `Supervisor.stop()`) stops all linked (supervised) actors:

```
final class SupervisorActor{
...
   override def postStop(): Unit = shutdownLinkedActors
```

However, when you want to shutdown all actors in the system gracefully, there's another [proper way to do that](https://github.com/jboner/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/ActorRegistry.scala#L257), using Actor Registry (that holds information about all the actors systemwide):

```
Actor.registry.shutdownAll
```