# Creating custom Akka Supervisor that shuts down all linked actors

Tags: scala, actor, akka

[This earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046079/in-akka-does-calling-shutdown-on-a-supervisor-stop-all-the-actors-its-supervisi) suggests that calling 'stop' on a supervisor actor will shut down all linked actors. However, if one creates a 'custom' actor (not through a factory), it seems that this auto-shutdown doesn't happen. For example, see this code from the answer to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861505/akka-supervisor-managing-supervisors):

```
class Module1 extends Actor {
   self.faultHandler = OneForOneStrategy(List(classOf[Throwable]), 5, 5000)

   def receive = {
       case Register(actor) =>
           self.link(actor)
   }
}
```

If 'stop' was called on the above Module1 actor, the actors linked to it wouldn't shut down. Is there a way to make a custom actor automatically shut down linked actors? Or is this just something that you have to write yourself if you want to create a custom actor?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call:

```
self.linkedActors.values.iterator
```

and then send a *PoisonPill* or *stop()* them.

Comment: being in a nit-picky mood: might be good to mention that postStop() is the perfect place to put this code ;-)

Comment: I saw some code like that in the SupervisorActor class in the Akka source code. So I could copy and paste that code from SupervisorActor into my own custom supervisor class for sure. I was just wondering if there was a better way than copy-and-paste coding. Are there any other behaviors that I need to copy and paste into my custom supervisor? Like the ability to restart child Actors that have crashed?

Comment: Nope, that should be it. Although, should be noted that you don't need to do it manually in 2.0-M1 and forward.